# Configuring screen, window problems

Tags: configuration, gnu-screen

I Have recently started configuring "screen", I have included my `.screenrc` below. I have a problem that if windows 0 & 1 (containing bash) are idle for about 10 mins they will close only leaving window 2 containing irssi. Have I done something wrong? is there something i can do to stop this from happening? I have tried searching for similar problems or solutions but I am finding it difficult to find anything relevant.

```
startup_message off
autodetach on

shell /bin/bash 
defutf8 on
altscreen on

hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{=kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B}%Y-%m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]'

defscrollback 30000

# Default screens
screen -t bash-0    0
screen -t bash-1    1
screen -t irssi     2   irssi

select 0
```

Comment: I don't quite get your window configuration, but even as a long time `screen` user, if you are just getting started i would recommend learning the much better behaved and actively developed `tmux` instead. GNU-Screen is full of quirks and hasn't been actively developed for some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the `TMOUT` environment variable set (nothing to do with `screen`)?  If it's set to 600, then bash will close the session after 600 seconds (10 minutes).

Comment: Agreed.  This doesn't sound like any screen behavior I've ever heard of.  It sounds like an inactivity logout from your shell.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem, a while after posting this i realised that it may also have been bash, but still did not know what to do about it.. Thanks